# Condition equivalent to a moduli space being a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold, and assume that it is foliated by a regular $p$-foliation. I know the following implication to be true:

> If for every point $m\in M$ there exists a submanifold $m\in S\subset M$ which intersects every leaf at most once and which is such that for every $x\in S$ we have $T_xM = T_xS\oplus T_xF$ (where $F$ denotes the leaf through $x$), then the moduli space of leaves is a manifold in a natural way.

By the *moduli space of leaves* I mean $M/\sim$, where $x\sim y$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are on the same leaf. The proof goes by using the local slices $S$ as charts for the moduli space.

My question is: is the converse also true?

I believe it is not, but I have not been able to find a counterexample as of yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have anything to say about your question in particular, but, I would recommend the work A. Lichernowicz, Global Theory of Connections ( 1976).

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Ok, I'll take a look. Tanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by "in a natural way." One way to interpret that phrase is to say that $M/{\sim}$ has a smooth manifold structure such that the projection $M\to M/{\sim}$ is a smooth submersion. In this case, the converse is true: The rank theorem guarantees that in a neighborhood of each point $m\in M$, there exist smooth coordinates on $M$ and smooth coordinates on $M/{\sim}$ in which the projection has the coordinate representation $(x^1,\dots,x^k,x^{k+1},\dots,x^n)\mapsto (x^1,\dots,x^k)$. You can take $S$ to be the submanifold defined by $x^{k+1}=\dots=x^n=0$.